# Turning a vector of values into a comma separated vector with quote around each

Tags: r, string, paste

I'd like to get the result so that it is show as:

> "6","4","8"

Or a comma

```
my_vector = base::unique(mtcars$cyl)
my_vector_quoted =paste(my_vector, sep=" ' ")
```

Now how do I get the commas in between?   I tried repeating this with the sep = ' but that doesn't work.

Any ways around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities assuming input `x`:

```
toString(dQuote(x, FALSE))

toString(sprintf('"%d"', x))

toString(shQuote(x, type = "cmd"))

paste(paste0('"', x, '"'), collapse = ", ")

# these use options

options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
toString(dQuote(x))

library(withr)
with_options(c(useFancyQuotes = FALSE), toString(dQuote(x)))
```

For example,

```
x <- c(6, 4, 8)
xs <- toString(dQuote(x, FALSE))

cat(xs, "\n")
## "6", "4", "8" 

# xs contains 13 characters and what they are

nchar(xs)
## [1] 13

strsplit(xs, "")[[1]] 
## [1] "\"" "6"  "\"" ","  " "  "\"" "4"  "\"" ","  " "  "\"" "8"  "\""

nchar(xs)
```

Comment: Good answers, but be sure to wrap in `cat` to print the desired output (i.e. "6","4","8")

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
my_vector_quoted =paste(my_vector, collapse=",")
#"6,4,8"
```

Comment: each number separated by quotes and commas.   this is halfway there.  i think solution above might work.

Comment: my_vector_quoted = paste(my_vector, collapse='","'), with output   

"6\",\"4\",\"8"